# GraphicsMagick for Node.js (GM Module) performance

Tags: node.js, png, graphicsmagick

I am seeing surprisingly slow performance from GraphicsMagick for Node.js using the GM npm module.

I have a simple 16px X 16px icon called icon16.png (320 Bytes).  I am simply taking a buffer of this PNG and outputting it to a new buffer using GM (in other words, I am just invoking GM and passing the image through with no manipulation in order to find the performance issue).

```
    var timeStart = parseInt(Date.now());
    var newBuffer = gm(icon16buffer, 'icon16.png')
        //.resize(8, 8)
        .toBuffer(function (err, buffer) {
            if (err) {
                next();
            }
            else {
                console.log(parseInt(Date.now()) - timeStart);
                send(200, buffer);
            }
        });
    };
```

This takes 175ms (ie. the console.log output is 175). Why so long? Does the C++ GraphicsMagick library have to be loaded from disk each time? Note: I am using SmartOS on Joyent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `gm` module calls out to a command-line tool. You might look at using [graphicsmagick2](https://github.com/Automattic/node-graphicsmagick) instead, which is an actual binding to the graphicsmagick library. Unfortunately there is no documentation, so you'll have to read the source for that (which isn't too long).

Answer (score 1):

You can try to compare Node.js modules for images manipulation - https://github.com/ivanoff/images-manipulation-performance

**Comparation example:**

```
  Found images:
  4198671-green-sea-view.jpg
  Beautiful-Sea-Pier-In-Chile-Hdr-Wide-Desktop-Background-Wallpapers-Beautiful-Sea-Wallpaper-.jpg
  Bluestone-valley-view_-_Virginia_-_ForestWander.jpg
Found modules: canvas.js, gm-imagemagic.js, gm.js, lwip.js
== START ==
canvas.js : 4.001 img/sec; done in 7.498536 sec; minCPUidle: 96%; minFreeMem: 283Mb; MaxLoadAvg: 1.48
gm-imagemagic.js : 1.206 img/sec; done in 24.88003 sec; minCPUidle: 96%; minFreeMem: 456Mb; MaxLoadAvg: 1.59
gm.js : 1.536 img/sec; done in 19.528429 sec; minCPUidle: 96%; minFreeMem: 490Mb; MaxLoadAvg: 1.84
lwip.js : 0.406 img/sec; done in 73.891623 sec; minCPUidle: 96%; minFreeMem: 157Mb; MaxLoadAvg: 1.56
== DONE ==
```

In this example you can see, than **canvas** module is the best, regards to speed of processing of images (~4 imgages per second on author's local computer)